# jQuery: Add file type class to links for ANY file type

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
$("a[href $='.pdf']" ).addClass("linkIconPDF");
$("a[href *='.pdf#']").addClass("linkIconPDF");
$("a[href *='.pdf;']").addClass("linkIconPDF");
$("a[href *='.pdf?']").addClass("linkIconPDF");

$("a[href $='.txt']" ).addClass("linkIconTXT");
$("a[href *='.txt#']").addClass("linkIconTXT");
$("a[href *='.txt;']").addClass("linkIconTXT");
$("a[href *='.txt?']").addClass("linkIconTXT");
```

So far so good, but how can it be simplified to match any file type?

Is it possible to do some regex grouping to match all possible file types like this?

```
$("a[href $='.([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})']" ).addClass("linkIcon$1");
```

Test script: http://jsfiddle.net/k2jqn/

Comment: The URLs ending with semicolons seem rather unlikely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var match = this.href.match(/\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})([#;?]|$)/);
    if(match){
        $(this).addClass("linkIcon" + match[1]);
    }
});
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/k2jqn/4/

Comment: @ZoltanToth You need to store the backreference and add it correctly, but the approach holds. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @Martin I just added that for debugging in Firefox, it doesn't actually have anything to do with what you want to achieve. I've already removed it from the answer.

Comment: @Martin Here's a demonstration without the `console.log` http://jsfiddle.net/k2jqn/5/

Comment: I figured it. Damn IE8 made me go nuts. It broke my CSS rule since it doesn't like attribute selectors like `.linkIcons a[href $=".pdf"], #inhalt:not(.keineLinkIconsInListen) li a[href $=".pdf"],
.linkIcons a[href *=".pdf#"], #inhalt:not(.keineLinkIconsInListen) li a[href *=".pdf#"],
.linkIcons a[href *=".pdf;"], #inhalt:not(.keineLinkIconsInListen) li a[href *=".pdf;"],
.linkIcons a[href *=".pdf?"], #inhalt:not(.keineLinkIconsInListen) li a[href *=".pdf?"]` Thanks again!

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Why the semicolon in `[#;?]`?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can simply use the wildcard selector:

```
$("a[href*='.pdf']" ).addClass("linkIconPDF");
$("a[href*='.txt']" ).addClass("linkIconTXT");
```

It selects the links in a wildcard way.

Comment: that's not safe enough, unlikely but possible example.com/foo.pdfiscool

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this

```
$("a[href $='.$']" ).addClass("linkIconANYFILE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Would an array with an each function be better than using a regex selector?

```
var fileTypes = new Array("a[href $='.pdf']","a[href *='.pdf#']");
fileTypes.each(function(index,val){
    $(val).addClass('LinkIconPDF');
});
```